# After form submit success message display

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, post

I'm working with form validations. The form validation is working fine. But the problem is after form submitted the success message div have to display and reset the form fields.
I have tried like this but didn't achieve the result.

```
  `if ($nameErr == '' && $emailErr == '' && $pwdErr == '' && $phErr == '' && $genderErr == '') {
         echo '<div class="msg_success" style="visibility: visible!important;">'.'</div>';

          }`
```

I newbie to the PHP. Can anyone suggest me what I'm doing wrong here and point me in the right direction. Below is my code.

**PHP code**

```
 $nameErr = '';
 $emailErr = '';
 $pwdErr  = '';
 $phErr = '';
 $genderErr = '';


 $user_name = '';
 $user_email = '';
 $user_password = '';
 $user_phone = '';
 $user_gender = '';

function test_input($data) {
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data;
}


if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    if (empty($_POST["user_name"])) {
        $nameErr = "Name is required";
    } else {
        $user_name = test_input($_POST["user_name"]);
        if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$user_name)) {
            $nameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 
        }
    }

    if (empty($_POST["user_email"])) {
        $emailErr = "Email is required";
    } else {
        $user_email = test_input($_POST["user_email"]);

        if (!filter_var($user_email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            $emailErr = "Invalid email format"; 
        }
    }

    if (empty($_POST["user_password"])) {
        $pwdErr = "Password is required";
    } else {
        $user_password = test_input($_POST["user_password"]);

        if (!preg_match("/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)[a-zA-Z\d]{8,}$/", $user_password)) {
            $pwdErr = "Use atleast one uppercase lowercase and digit"; 
        }
    }

    if (empty($_POST["user_phone"])) {
        $phErr = "Phone number is required";
    } else {
        $user_phone = test_input($_POST["user_phone"]);
        if (!preg_match("/^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$/",$user_phone)) {
            $phErr = "Invalid phone number"; 
        }
    }

    if (empty($_POST["user_gender"])) {
        $genderErr = "Gender is required";
    } else{
        $user_gender = test_input($_POST["user_gender"]);
        if ($user_gender == "Male"){
            $Mchecked = "checked";
        }
        else if ($user_gender == "Female"){
            $Fchecked = "checked";
        }

    }

    // if ($nameErr == '' && $emailErr == '' && $pwdErr == '' && $phErr == '' && $genderErr == '') {
    //  echo '<div class="msg_success" style="visibility: visible!important;">'.'</div>';

    // }

}
?>
```

**HTML code**

```
<div class="at_wrapper">
<div class="at_inner">
    <div class="registerorm">
        <form method="POST" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" novalidate autocomplete="off">
            <div class="fields">
                <label>Name</label>
                <input type="text" name="user_name" value="">
            </div>
                <span class="error"><?php echo $nameErr;?></span>
            <div class="fields">
                <label>Email</label>
                <input type="email" name="user_email" value="">
            </div>
            <span class="error"><?php echo $emailErr;?></span>
            <div class="fields">
                <label>Password</label>
                <input type="password" name="user_password" value="">
            </div>
            <span class="error"><?php echo $pwdErr;?></span>
            <div class="fields">
                <label>Phone Number</label>
                <input type="number" name="user_phone" value="">
            </div>
            <span class="error"><?php echo $phErr;?></span>
            <div class="fields">
                <label>Gender</label>
                <span class="fgender">
                    <input type="radio" name="user_gender" value="Male">Male
                    <input type="radio" name="user_gender" value="Female">Female
                </span>
            </div>
            <span class="error"><?php echo $genderErr;?></span>
            <div class="btn">
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send" class="btn_submit">
            </div>
            <div class="msg_success">
                <p>Successfully Sent</p>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.msg_success {
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
border-radius: 10px;
visibility: hidden;
background: #9ce29c;
animation: cssAnimation 5s forwards;
animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
  .msg_success p {
      font-size: 24px;
      font-weight: 800;
     letter-spacing: 4px;
       color: green;
   }
  .error {
      display: flex;
       justify-content: flex-end;
      font-size: 12px;
      font-weight: 500;
      font-family: sans-serif;
     color: red;
  }

   @keyframes cssAnimation {
        0%   {opacity: 1;}
        90%  {opacity: 1;}
       100% {opacity: 0;}
    }
```

Comment: Well to start your missing a few `<?php` and `?>` tags.  Especially before this `<div class="at_wrapper">` you should have a `?>`

Comment: @ ArtisticPhoenix  All code I have written in the same file php tag is there the condition I wrote is correct? why success msg is not coming what might be the issue here.

Comment: Well in what you posed above, your missing the closing PHP tag, before the HTML.  So that's either a typo in the question, or you will probably be rendering PHP code in the source-code of your HTML page.  All I know is what you posted, I'm not Psychic.  `All code I have written in the same file` Why not post the whole file then instead of chopping it up.

Comment: No problem .... ;-p

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix Still message is not displayed.

Comment: What is displayed,  First off your code is very hard to read, very messy.  I would use an array for the errors, and user data.  That would clean it up quite a bit.  instead of `f ($nameErr == '' && $emailErr == '' && $pwdErr == '' && $phErr == '' && $genderErr == '')` you could do `if(!count($errors))`  it's too much for me to refactor it right now (feeling lazy...)

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix Not a problem whenever you feel to modify my code you can : )